# jQuery: insert a <li> tag into a list in order

Tags: jquery, insert

I have an order of `<li>` tags:

```
var order = ["a-link", "b-link", "c-link", "d-link", "e-link", "f-link"];
```

Some of the `<li>` tags might or might not be on the list at any given moment:

i.e.

```
<ul>
<li id="a-link"></li>
<li id="d-link"></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to be able to say, insert a `<li>` tag in it's right order...

```
    <ul>
        <li id="a-link"></li> 
<!-- i'd like to insert <li id="b-link"> right after this -->
        <li id="d-link"></li>
    </ul>
```

Sometimes my list might look like this:

```
    <ul>
    <li id="b-link"></li>

<!-- but maybe I want to insert a <li id="d-link"> here-->

    <li id="e-link"></li>
    </ul>
```

Or like this:

```
    <ul>
    <li id="a-link"></li>
    <li id="d-link"></li>
<!-- but maybe I want to insert a <li id="e-link"> here-->
    <li id="f-link"></li>
    </ul>
```

Basically, the list might change...but whenever I want to insert a `<li>` tag (one at a time) it needs to be placed in the right order as the order array.

Comment: You've got to clarify something for me, and you may want to clarify it in your question for future readers. Are you saying you want to insert the first one missing from the order, or are you saying you want to manually choose which one to insert, and you want it in the proper place? The example you gave could be interpreted either way.

Comment: I added in some other examples, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the question appears to be different than the other answerers (is that a word?).

My understanding of the question is that you want to insert a single element into a page where an unknown number of the other elements already exists.  You want this single element to be inserted into the list in the order defined by your array.

---

EDIT: Another option which could have better performance would be to find the index in the order array of the element you wish to insert.  Then loop from that index to the end.  As soon as you find an element which exists, insert your new element before that one.

http://jsfiddle.net/bWPX8/5/

```
var order = ["a-link", "b-link", "c-link", "d-link", "e-link", "f-link"];        

var toInsert = "c-link";
var insertIndex = order.indexOf(toInsert);

if($("ul>li").length === 0){

    $("ul").append(  $("<li>",{id:toInsert}));

}else if($("#"+toInsert).length===0){
    var inserted = false;

    for(var i = insertIndex + 1, len = order.length; i<len; i++){
        var $el = $("#" + order[i]);

        if($el.length > 0){
            $el.before($("<li>",{id:toInsert}));
            inserted = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!inserted){
         // should be last
          $("ul").append($("<li>",{id:toInsert}));
    }
}
```

For even better performance, determine whether the index of your element is before or after the midway point of the array and either loop forward or backwards depending on which would be less iterations of the loop.

---

If that is the question, here is a brute-force way to do it.  If the list is considerably larger than the example given the performance may not be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/bWPX8/3/

`Array.indexOf` may not be supported by some version of IE, so this may have to be replaced with something else.

Comment: There will only be a few (under 12) elements in the order, so I think the solution provided works well. But it's good to know the other optimizations so thanks for providing that.

Comment: *"different than the other answerers"* I'm the only other answer here, but our solutions behave identically. Were you referring to someone else's answer? (I can't see deleted ones yet.)

Comment: @RightSaidFred There have been multiple deleted answers.  Yours I did not have a chance to fully examine.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Alright. Thanks for the info. I think I remember seeing one other, but I never really looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

*To add a solution for the updated information in question:*

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
    lis = ul.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    order = ["a-link", "b-link", "c-link", "d-link", "e-link", "f-link"],
    toInsert = "b-link",
    i = $.inArray( toInsert, order ),
    el = lis[ toInsert ],
    new_li;

if( !el && i > -1 ) {
    do el = lis[ order[ ++i ] ];
    while( i < order.length && !el )

    (new_li = document.createElement('li')).id = new_li.innerHTML = toInsert;

    if( el ) ul.insertBefore( new_li, el );
    else ul.appendChild( new_li );
}
```

This takes advantage of "live" lists, and the fact that elements in the list are accessible by using their ID as a property of the list.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JjyAH/1/)**

---

***original answer:***

This should do it:

```
var order = ["a-link", "b-link", "c-link", "d-link", "e-link", "f-link"],
    i = 0,
    place = $('ul'),
    el = $('#' + order[i] );

if( !el.length ) {

    $('<li>',{id:order[i]}).prependTo( place );

} else {

    do {
        ++i;
        place = el;
        el = $('#' + order[i] );
    } while( el.length )

    if( i < order.length ) {
        $('<li>',{id:order[i]}).insertAfter( place );
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bWPX8/7/)**

---

*Here's another way to do it:*

```
var order = ["a-link", "b-link", "c-link", "d-link", "e-link", "f-link"],
    prev,
    el;

$.each( order, function(i,v) {
    prev = el;
    el = $('#' + v);
    if( !el.length ) {
        if( !i ) {
            $('<li>',{id:order[i],text:order[i]}).appendTo('ul');
        } else {
            $('<li>',{id:order[i],text:order[i]}).insertAfter( prev );
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bWPX8/9/)**

Comment: Seems to fail with anything other than `i=0`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I'm not sure what you mean. `i` is the starting point of the analysis, so it should never be changed.

Comment: Oh, so OP wanted to determine the one to insert? It sounded in the question like it was the next one in the natural order. Guess not.